# What is the best approach to monitor Wifi signal strength on Android

Tags: android, wifi, android-wifi

I am developing an application which has a strong relation with the network. It has to be connected with a strong wifi signal. I got the experience once when I developed an application it was rejected by the users because it also had a strong relation with the network, but the wifi network didn´t work very well, so the users blamed the application and they drop it out.

Now I will develop a new application and I want to prevent to this happens again. First I am extending the BroadcastReceiver so the app will be notified when the connection is lost.

```
public class ConnectivityReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
public static ConnectivityReceiverListener connectivityReceiverListener = null;
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    boolean isConnected =  AppUtilities.getWifiConnectionStatus(context);

    if(connectivityReceiverListener != null){
        connectivityReceiverListener.showMessageStatus(isConnected);
    }
}

public interface ConnectivityReceiverListener {

    void showMessageStatus(boolean status);
}


}
```

Now I need to monitor the wifi signal strength to notified the user when the signal goes low.
I already have a method that measures the signal strength and returns an integer from 0 to 4 that represents the signals strength from low to high.

```
    public static int getWifiStrengh(Context context){
    WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    int numberOfLevels = 5;
    WifiInfo wifiInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
    int level = WifiManager.calculateSignalLevel(wifiInfo.getRssi(), numberOfLevels);
    return level;
}
```

Now getting to the point, I want to know which will be the best approach to constantly monitor the signal strength.

I´m thinking in use job scheduler to constantly monitor the signal strength and changing the bar color (like a red one) when the signal strength is less than 2 to notified the user. But I would like to know if there is a better approach to solving this problem.

Answer (score 0):

For those who wants to know how I did it. I used Job Scheduler because it is a task that needs to have wifi connection established.

Also, you can check [my blog](https://davidmatablog.wordpress.com/) where you will find more details about this and extra information

At the end, I got this
[image]

First, declare a text view on every activity.

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/messageLogin"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/wifitoSlow"
        android:textColor="@color/magnitude0"
        android:background="@color/magnitude7"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:visibility="gone"
        />
```

Then I create a Class WfiJob who has the JobCheduler who requires NETWORK_TYPE_ANY, and it does it every 5 seconds.

```
public class WifiJob {

public void createWifiJob(int jobNumber, Context context){
    //We are defining a jobObject that will have a jobNumber and a serviceName that will run only if a network connection exits
    JobScheduler jobScheduler = (JobScheduler)context.getSystemService(Context.JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE);
    jobScheduler.schedule(new JobInfo.Builder(jobNumber, new ComponentName(context.getApplicationContext(), WifiJobScheduler.class))
            .setRequiredNetworkType(JobInfo.NETWORK_TYPE_ANY)
            .setRequiresDeviceIdle(false)
            .setPeriodic(5000).build());
}
}
```

Then my WifiJobScheduler that extends from JobService. In here I also have the WifiStrenghtListener wich is an interface that will broadcast a message to the activities so the can show the textview.

```
public class WifiJobScheduler extends JobService{


private static final String TAG = "SyncService";
public static WifiStrenghtListener wifiStrenghtListener=null;
//private boolean messageIsShowed = false;
//The onStartJob is performed in the main thread, if you start asynchronous processing in this method, return true otherwise false.
@Override
public boolean onStartJob(JobParameters params) {
    Log.i(TAG, "on start job: " + params.getJobId());
    PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    if(AppUtilities.isInteractive(pm) ){ //if the device is active
        int wifiStrenght = WifiUtilities.getWifiStrengh(getApplicationContext());
        Log.i(TAG, "wifi strengh ........... : " + wifiStrenght);
        if(wifiStrenghtListener!=null){
            if(wifiStrenght<4 && !AppUtilities.messageIsShowed){
                wifiStrenghtListener.showSlowSignalOnTop(View.VISIBLE);
                AppUtilities.messageIsShowed = true;
            }else if(wifiStrenght>3 && AppUtilities.messageIsShowed){
                wifiStrenghtListener.showSlowSignalOnTop(View.GONE);
                AppUtilities.messageIsShowed = false;
            }

        }

    }else{
        cancelAllJobs();
        Log.i(TAG, "job canceled........");
    }

    return false; // true if we're not done yet and we are going to run this on a thread
}

// If the job fails for some reason, return true from on the onStopJob to restart the job.
@Override
public boolean onStopJob(JobParameters params) {

    return true;
}

public void cancelAllJobs() {
    JobScheduler tm = (JobScheduler) getSystemService(Context.JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE);
    tm.cancelAll();
}

public interface WifiStrenghtListener{

    void showSlowSignalOnTop(int visible);
}
}
```

The controller to subscribe the activities.

```
public class WifiJobSchedulerController {

public void setWifiJobSchedulerControllerInstance(WifiJobScheduler.WifiStrenghtListener listener){

    WifiJobScheduler.wifiStrenghtListener = listener;
}
}
```

And finally, you need to implement the interface and subscribe the activity.

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements  WifiJobScheduler.WifiStrenghtListener {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);      
    //register wifistrenght status listener
    new WifiJobSchedulerController().setWifiJobSchedulerControllerInstance(this);
}
    @Override
public void showSlowSignalOnTop(int visible) {
    TextView message = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.messageLogin);
    message.setVisibility(visible);
}
}
```